# Show an image when hovering over a div... but in a x a grid of divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, mousehover

I'm building a project where I have to make a grid of divs and then make something appear when you hover over them. You can do it with a background-color, like you hover over them and they change background color. But I'd like to try something different.

I'd like to divide an image for the entire a x a grid of divs so that, when you hover over a div it shows you just a piece of the full image. In this way, to show the entire image, you have to hover over all the divs!

Could you help me to achive this target?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you wanting the pieces of the image to stay visible when you stop hovering the divs in the grid? Or only *while* they are being hovered?

Comment: @DeclanMcKelvey-Hembree Hi! yes I was aking for the first option. But if I wanted to do the second option? I would try by myself first but if I got stuck, should I return here to the same question and ask for a new help or open a new question?

Comment: I'd ask a new question, but should be pretty simple using the CSS `:hover` selector.

Comment: @DeclanMcKelvey-Hembree Got it!

Answer (score 0):

You basically just want to fade out the divs when they're hovered to expose a background image below, like so:

```js
function fade(element){
  element.classList.add("grid-cell--transparent");
}

function reset(){
  var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-cell");
  for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
    cells[i].classList.remove("grid-cell--transparent");
  }
}
```

```css
.grid-container{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200);
    background-size: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-cell{
  background: aquamarine;
  border: 1px solid green;
  transition: background 1s, border 1s;
}

.grid-cell--transparent{
  background: transparent;
  border: 0px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-cell" onmouseover="fade(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-cell" onmouseover="fade(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-cell" onmouseover="fade(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-cell" onmouseover="fade(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-cell" onmouseover="fade(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-cell" onmouseover="fade(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-cell" onmouseover="fade(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-cell" onmouseover="fade(this)"></div>
  <div class="grid-cell" onmouseover="fade(this)"></div>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```